# Run Quartz Scheduler on a specific TimeZone

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler to schedule some jobs. Below are my requirement.

- All the jobs has to run at 00:00 hrs (EST).
- All the jobs will run everyday except Saturday.

So the 2nd one is working fine. But instead of running it on EST it currently runs on GMT. Though i have set the Timezone as EST.

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
WeeklyCalendar  weeklyOff = new WeeklyCalendar ();
weeklyOff.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("est"));
weeklyOff.setDayExcluded(java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY, true);
scheduler.addCalendar("weeklyOff", weeklyOff, false,false);


JobDetail jobScheduleScan = JobBuilder.newJob(jobScheduleScan.class).withIdentity("scheduleScan", "alpaca").build();


Trigger triggerScheduleScan = TriggerBuilder
                        .newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("scheduleTrigger", "alpaca")
                        .startNow()
                        //.withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(1).repeatForever())
                        .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(00, 00).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("est"))) 
                        .modifiedByCalendar("weeklyOff")
                        .build();


scheduler.scheduleJob(jobScheduleScan,triggerScheduleScan);

scheduler.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("est")
```

I suspect you write:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("est"));
```

you'll get something like

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

Basically "est" isn't a valid time zone ID. I suspect you don't mean "EST" anyway, but "Eastern Time" which is EST and EDT, switching appropriately. For that, you should use an ID of "America/New_York", so:

```
weeklyOff.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

If you *really* want a fixed time zone of UTC-5, you can use:

```
weeklyOff.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));
```

Comment: i Have tried 

System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));

But its not working. Throwing the Same which you mentioned earlier. sun.utill.calendar.ZoneInfo..........

Comment: @Angel: Both of those show an ID of "GMT"? That's very unusual - *particularly* for the latter one, as that's the specified way of constructing fixed-offset time zones. What JVM are you running, and under what OS? What does `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs` return?

Comment: Thank you. TimeZone.getAvailableIDs has helped me. Actually It Should "EST" instead of "est". it fixed now.

Comment: @Angel: But "EST" is still a *broken* way of describing it... I'm really concerned if neither America/New_York or GMT-05:00 works. I wouldn't even like to guess whether "EST" as an identifier is actually Eastern time, or whether it's fixed. I would strongly encourage you to investigate this further, as it may be a significant issue in the platform you're running on.